# Allow users to add multiple items to ObservableCollection c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a ListView that should populate based on user inputs. The ListView is binded to my ObservableCollection. When user adds an item, it inserts but immediately after when I do another add, the previous item is removed and replaced with the latest added item(Making the list items 1 instead of 2). How can I fix this?

**Code:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                TxtEntry.Text
            };


            MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are creating a new collection each time.

Change your code like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public YourConstructor()
{
   MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Items.Add(TxtEntry.Text);
}
```

What you see happening here is the collection is instantiated when the property is created for the first time.

Then, in the constructor of your object, set the `ItemSource` of the `ListView` to the `ObservableCollection` and then whenever the button is clicked, simply add the item, instead of creating a whole new collection each time.

Also, you don't need to set the `ItemSource` each time. Because it is an `ObservableCollection` the `ListView` will be notified of any changes in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You should add it to the list, not re-create the list:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Items == null) 
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            TxtEntry.Text
        };
    } 
    else {
        Items.Add(TxtEntry.Text);
    }
    MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
}
```